# Why is python freezing with no exception raised

Tags: python, exception, scheduled-tasks

We are running a python mail processing script from a Windows server. The applications checks a mailbox every 30 seconds and then does things like downloads attachments, manipulate them, copy them to an ftp, writes into a database and send response mails.

Sometimes an error is encountered and there is exception handling and logging in place to help us identify what went wrong.

However, sometimes the script just freezes without any errors being logged or exceptions raised. It sometimes happens while the script was processing mails/documents, other times while there was nothing in the mailbox and the script was just checking every 30s. We are sort of at a loss on how to find the root cause.

We have put in place a work-around where the application ends itself every hour (on the hour) and then the Windows Task scheduler starts it again 2 minutes later. We've also monitored system resources to see if there may be some memory leak or other over-taxing of the resources, but it does not seem to be the case.

What methods can we follow to identify the issue, and what possible causes can we look out for?

Here is some more detail about the setup:

- Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit  Intel Core 2 Duo CPU @2.4GHz
- 16 GB Ram
- Python version 3.10.1
- some dependencies used: email, imaplib, smtplib, ssl, xml, mysql, PyPDF2

The high level loop that the code follows is something like this:

```
# Check mails and process every 30 seconds, forever
while True:
    try:
        logger.info(f"Checking mailbox...  (iteration nr {i})")
        process_data_collection_emails(mail_client, processing_map, logger, env, current_hour)
        i += 1
        sleep(30)
        hour_now = datetime.now().hour
        if hour_now > current_hour:
            log_hour_to_file(hour_now, "crash_check.txt")
            exit()

        if i > 120:  # restarts middleware after approx. 1 hour to prevent too many consecutive requests
            os.execv(sys.executable, ['python' + ('3.9' if env == "linux" else "")] + sys.argv)
            i = 1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()

    except ConnectionResetError:
        logger.exception("message")
        logger.info("\nThat was a connection reset error, so we wait 90s")
        sleep(90)

    except SystemExit:
        exit()

    except:
        logger.exception("message")
        logger.info("\nThat was an error, so we wait 20s")
        sleep(20)
        mail_client = imap_log_in(*mail_connect)
```

Comment: You have a loop with the condition `i > 0`. That is, you keep on looping while the value of `i` is larger than zero. But nowhere in the code do I see you ever decreasing the value of `i`, or setting it to zero (or making it negative). So when will the loop condition ever become false and break the loop?

Comment: The code is meant to run forever, so: nowhere.

Comment: Then why not an explicit infinite loop like `while True`? Also, proper documentation in the source (comments) about it would be useful.

Comment: OK, good remark. I'll implement your suggestion and re-post the code.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to run in a debugger and break it when the "freeze" happens, to see when and where in your code it seems to happen? And you're aware of that [`os.execv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execv) will never return (unless there's an error)?

Comment: Sort of. The issue is that the freezing is unpredictable. Usually when we run the code everything runs smoothly. The freezing only happens when we leave the code running for a long time (sometimes it goes days with no issue).

Comment: Then the only solution is more logging! Add logging for *everything* you do, for every function called, for every return of called functions. It's a lot of work, tedious and unrewarding, but that's a part of being a professional programmer. :)

Comment: Also, I hope you're using some kind of VCS (Version Control System) like Git etc., because then once you have figured out the problem and how to solve it, it's easy to roll back the extra logging that is no longer needed and cherry-pick the fix. Or you add logging categories for tracing that can be enabled or disabled when and if needed, so you can use it if needed sometime in the future.

Comment: Yes, we use git :) Also, logger let's you specify logging level e.g. `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` , so it's possible to add tons of debug level logs and then when you found your issue, you just set the level to INFO and your log file is clean again.